# How to connect EMR in VPC subnet to a redshift instance in ec2-classic?

Tags: amazon-redshift, amazon-emr, amazon-vpc

We have a redshift cluster which is **not in VPC** and I have been trying to connect to it from an EMR cluster in VPC(attached internet gateway) with no luck so far. I would like to know if there is a possible way of doing that.

Note - I have already tried launching a new redshift cluster in VPC public subnet and was able to connect to it from EMR in the same subnet.

Comment: Coming back to the same question again if anyone can help out. It will save some effort as we will not end up migrating the cluster to VPC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reached out to the AWS support team and got to know that the connection from EMR in VPC to redshift in ec2-classic is not possible. The solution would be to either launch the EMR in ec2-classic or restore the redshift cluster in VPC. We went ahead with the second option(restoring the redshift cluster in VPC) and it was pretty straightforward.

Adding references below-
https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/redshift/latest/dg/load-from-emr-steps-create-cluster.html

"If the Amazon Redshift cluster is in a VPC, the Amazon EMR cluster must be in the same VPC group. If the Amazon Redshift cluster uses EC2-Classic mode (that is, it is not in a VPC), the Amazon EMR cluster must also use EC2-Classic mode"

The best possible approach would be to move the Redshift cluster in the VPC to connect to the EMR cluster. To achieve this you can take a snapshot

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/managing-snapshots-console.html#snapshot-create

of the Redshift cluster then create a new cluster in the VPC from the snapshot

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/managing-snapshots-console.html#snapshot-restore

Thereafter, you can modify the security group rule to add an EMR security group in your Redshift cluster. The steps are outlined here

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/managing-security-groups-console.html#security-group-modify